# Jquery - if statement match various criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, contains

I want to run some functions on clicking a link but I want to exclude links that match certain criteria... I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this, but it still seems to be running the function on a link with the href of `#top`.

```
$('a').click(function () {
    if(($(this).not('[href*="#"]') && $(this).not(".TypesOfProperties") && $(this).not('[target]')) || $(this).is('[target="_parent"]')) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
});
```

And...

```
<a href='#top'>Don't run function</a>
<a class='.TypesOfProperties' href='/mypage'>Don't run function</a>
<a target='_blank' href='/mypage'>Don't run function</a>

<a href='/mypage'>Do run function</a>
<a target='_parent' href='/mypage'>Do run function</a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: provide html code too

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to create a handler for the criteria you want, not filtering out all the ones you don't want. Surely there must be something setting apart these links.

Comment: One minor point: You have a syntax error in your code. There should be a closing parenthesis (and for good form, a terminating semicolon) after the final curly brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).not(...)` is not a check, it removes elements that don't satisfy the given condition.
So if you click `<a href="#top">` then `$(this).not('[href*="#"]')` returns an empty jQuery object.

You can check the length (and multiple selectors):

```
if ($(this).not('[href*="#"] , .TypesOfProperties').length || $(this).is('[target="_parent"]')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you will bind less unnecessary handlers.

```
$('a[target="_parent"]').not('[href*="#"],.TypesOfProperties,[target]').click(function() {
     // DO SOMETHING
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `.is()`, `.not()` does not return true or false, it return a jQuery object.

*Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .not() method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements. The supplied selector is tested against each element; the elements that don't match the selector will be included in the result.*

jQuery doc : http://api.jquery.com/not/

If you want you statement to work, you need to check the length like that :

```
if(($(this).not('[href*="#"], .TypesOfProperties, [target]').length) || $(this).is('[target="_parent"]'))
```

If `length = 0`, it is the same thing as false.

Comment: `.is(), not does not return true or false` - realy?

Comment: "Unlike .is(), .not() does not"